# Pull to dismiss React Navigation Modal

Tags: android, ios, react-native, frontend, react-navigation

I am using gestureRespondeDistance: `{vertical:Dimensions.get('window').height}` on my mode modal screen in stackNavigator. The problem is that I have a ScrollView inside, so the swipe down to dismiss gesture is not called because of the list. Swipe to dismiss should be called when the scrollview reach offset 0 on Y axis. I know that there are a lot of modal libraries that fix this but I can't use them with the navigation. I have to find a solution to make it work inside the stackNavigator. I would appreciate an example of this!